# Android MediaPlayer won't work on android 4.0 ice cream sandwich

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Ive made an app that plays media from an on line source using a mediaplayer,it works on my phone which is running android 2.3.7 gingerbread, but when i try and run it on another phone running android 4.0 it crashes when the play button is pressed. I've searched everywhere and just cant find the solution to the problem. Any help would be very much appreciated.My code and results of the log are below:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint({ "UseValueOf", "UseValueOf" })
public class DisplayMessage5 extends Activity
implements Runnable, OnClickListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private ImageButton play;
    private ImageButton pause;
    private ImageButton stop;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private TextView textViewSecs;
    private TextView textViewTotal;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message5);
        play = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        pause = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
        stop = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
        seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        textViewSecs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.progress_text_secs);
        textViewTotal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.progress_text_mins);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        play.setOnClickListener(this);
        pause.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_display_message5, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        int currentPosition= 0;
        int total = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        while (mediaPlayer!=null && currentPosition<total) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                currentPosition= mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }            
            seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
        }

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.equals(play)) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) return;
            if(seekBar.getProgress() > 0) {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();
                return;
            }
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("myurl");
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
            new Thread(this).start();
        }

        if (pause.isPressed()) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        } 

        if(stop.isPressed()){
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        int progressSecs = (progress / 1000) % 60;
        int progressMins = (progress / 1000) / 60;
        int totalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        int totalSecs = (totalTime / 1000) % 60;
        int totalMins = ((totalTime / 1000) / 60) % 60;
        int totalHours = totalTime / 1000 / 60 / 60;
        textViewSecs.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%02d", progressMins)) + ":" + String.valueOf(String.format("%02d", progressSecs)));
        textViewTotal.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%02d", totalHours)) + ":" + String.valueOf(String.format("%02d", totalMins)) + ":" + String.valueOf(String.format("%02d", totalSecs)));
        if(fromUser){
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekbar) {


    }



}
```

log

```
10-10 20:15:47.156: E/AndroidRuntime(15124): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 20:15:47.156: E/AndroidRuntime(15124): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 20:15:47.156: E/AndroidRuntime(15124):    at com.marnis.na.shares.DisplayMessage5.onClick(DisplayMessage5.java:86)
10-10 20:15:47.156: E/AndroidRuntime(15124):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
10-10 20:15:47.156: E/AndroidRuntime(15124):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
10-10 20:15:47.156: E/AndroidRuntime(15124):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-10 20:15:47.156: E/AndroidRuntime(15124):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-10 20:15:47.156: E/AndroidRuntime(15124):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 20:15:47.156: E/AndroidRuntime(15124):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4613)
10-10 20:15:47.156: E/AndroidRuntime(15124):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 20:15:47.156: E/AndroidRuntime(15124):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 20:15:47.156: E/AndroidRuntime(15124):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
10-10 20:15:47.156: E/AndroidRuntime(15124):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
10-10 20:15:47.156: E/AndroidRuntime(15124):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 20:15:48.119: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:48.176: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:48.686: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:48.686: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:49.186: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:49.186: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:49.686: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:49.686: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:50.186: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:50.186: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:50.686: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:50.686: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:51.196: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:51.196: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:51.696: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:51.696: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:52.196: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:52.196: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:52.696: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:52.696: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:53.198: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:53.198: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:53.706: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:53.706: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:54.206: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:54.206: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:54.706: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:54.706: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:55.206: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:55.216: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:55.706: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:55.716: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:56.207: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:56.216: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:56.706: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:56.706: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:57.206: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:57.206: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:15:57.706: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:15:57.706: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:16:47.626: I/dalvikvm(15124): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:16:47.666: I/dalvikvm(15124): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:20:47.226: I/Process(15124): Sending signal. PID: 15124 SIG: 9
10-10 20:21:50.226: V/ActivityThread(15667): com.marnis.na.shares white listed for hwui
10-10 20:21:50.536: D/libEGL(15667): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
10-10 20:21:50.576: D/libEGL(15667): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
10-10 20:21:50.626: I/dalvikvm(15667): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:21:50.657: I/dalvikvm(15667): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:21:50.746: D/libEGL(15667): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
10-10 20:21:50.766: D/libEGL(15667): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
10-10 20:21:50.796: D/OpenGLRenderer(15667): Enabling debug mode 0
10-10 20:21:53.796: D/OpenGLRenderer(15667): Flushing caches (mode 0)
10-10 20:21:55.966: D/MediaPlayer(15667): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
10-10 20:21:55.996: E/MediaPlayer(15667): Unable to to create media player
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667): create failed:
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:844)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:806)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:761)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:695)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:676)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at com.marnis.na.shares.DisplayMessage4.onClick(DisplayMessage4.java:77)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4613)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/MediaPlayer(15667):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 20:21:56.026: D/AndroidRuntime(15667): Shutting down VM
10-10 20:21:56.026: W/dalvikvm(15667): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a2f3f8)
10-10 20:21:56.026: E/AndroidRuntime(15667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 20:21:56.026: E/AndroidRuntime(15667): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 20:21:56.026: E/AndroidRuntime(15667):    at com.marnis.na.shares.DisplayMessage4.onClick(DisplayMessage4.java:79)
10-10 20:21:56.026: E/AndroidRuntime(15667):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
10-10 20:21:56.026: E/AndroidRuntime(15667):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
10-10 20:21:56.026: E/AndroidRuntime(15667):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-10 20:21:56.026: E/AndroidRuntime(15667):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-10 20:21:56.026: E/AndroidRuntime(15667):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 20:21:56.026: E/AndroidRuntime(15667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4613)
10-10 20:21:56.026: E/AndroidRuntime(15667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 20:21:56.026: E/AndroidRuntime(15667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 20:21:56.026: E/AndroidRuntime(15667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
10-10 20:21:56.026: E/AndroidRuntime(15667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
10-10 20:21:56.026: E/AndroidRuntime(15667):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 20:21:56.556: I/dalvikvm(15667): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:21:56.566: I/dalvikvm(15667): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:21:57.086: I/dalvikvm(15667): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:21:57.096: I/dalvikvm(15667): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:21:57.586: I/dalvikvm(15667): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:21:57.596: I/dalvikvm(15667): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:21:58.096: I/dalvikvm(15667): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:21:58.106: I/dalvikvm(15667): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:21:58.596: I/dalvikvm(15667): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:21:58.606: I/dalvikvm(15667): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:21:59.097: I/dalvikvm(15667): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:21:59.097: I/dalvikvm(15667): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:21:59.596: I/dalvikvm(15667): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:21:59.596: I/dalvikvm(15667): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:22:00.096: I/dalvikvm(15667): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:22:00.096: I/dalvikvm(15667): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:22:00.597: I/dalvikvm(15667): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:22:00.606: I/dalvikvm(15667): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:22:01.096: I/dalvikvm(15667): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 20:22:01.096: I/dalvikvm(15667): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 20:22:01.306: I/Process(15667): Sending signal. PID: 15667 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What line is this in your program? (line 86) `at com.marnis.na.shares.DisplayMessage5.onClick(DisplayMessage5.java:86)`

Comment: there are two "mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();" lines in the onClick() method line 86 is the second one. it seems tobe unable to prepare the mediaplayer. But what I don't understand is why it works on my phone running 2.3.7 and not on 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(seekBar.getProgress() > 0) {
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } 
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        mediaPlayer.start();
        return;
}
```

The error happens because you try to access a method of a null object (mediaPlayer). It may happen in IF block because default value of your seekBar is not 0. In this case, you should initialize mediaPlayer in onCreate method better than in onClick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this solved the error but created a new one.